# Как сделать так, что бы элементы дрыгались так же

Tags: jquery, css, css-animation

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать так же как на этом сайте (http://enjoyme.ru/box/), в исходниках смотрел, что они делают это при помощи jQuery и background-position, но понять, как именно это работает я не могу. Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заглянули бы еще глубже, нашли бы вот это:

Картинка сделана спрайтом.

Скрипт просто меняет позицию фона из спрайта.

Анимация делается с помощью `setInterval()`

```js
    function updSprite() {
      var $element = $('.animated');
      var position = $element.css('background-position');
      if (position == '0px 100%') {
        position = '0 0'
      } else {
        position = '0px 100%'
      }
      $element.css('background-position', position);
    }
    setInterval(updSprite, 100);
```

```css
.animated{width: 113px; height: 73px; background: #000 url("http://oi64.tinypic.com/23qyws3.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animated"></div>
```